# Run NUnit webdriver tests in Bamboo

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, continuous-integration, bamboo, devops

I'm trying to setup a job in Bamboo to run some function tests written in Visual Studio 2015 with C# and Webdriver and I can[t find any specific documentation on how to run this tests in Bamboo. I have the sln file I build it on my machine and a playlist is generated with all the tests, how can I do this steps in Atlassian Bamboo? Does anyone have one information / tips I can use?

Comment: Have you tried looking at [the documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/configuring-a-test-task-289277052.html)?

Comment: I did..still can't figure it out why tests are not running. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out? I have found so many tutorials and videos, but I still cannot just run a Selenium test against a deploy. Could pretty pretty please explain in detail how you got this to work? Or did you give up on it?

Answer (score 0):

You should have three steps to configure what you are asking for:

- Use *Selenium Grid*. The goal is to have a hub (and at least one node). You can find the documentation on [seleniumhq.github.io](https://seleniumhq.github.io/docs/grid.html) : Suppose you are using *Selenium Grid* on http://a.b.c.d:4444/;

  - You can run the selenium's hub:

    ```
    java -jar selenium-server-standalone.jar -role hub
    ```
  - You can run the selenium's node (connected to the hub). For example, if you want to use the [IEDriver](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.53/), you can run your node using

    ```
    java -Dwebdriver.ie.driver=IEDriverServer.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar -port 5555 -role node -hub http://a.b.c.d:4444/grid/register -browser "browserName=internet explorer,version=11,platform=WINDOWS,maxInstances=10"
    ```
- You need to have NUnit tests using a remote web driver. For example:

  ```
  DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.InternetExplorer();
  var driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://a.b.c.d:4444/wd/hub"), capability);

  driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.ch");
  ```
- In your Bamboo task's configuration, you need to have a NUnit Runner configuration (as well as a NUnit parser if you want to get the results).

Comment: Hello Julien and thanks for your reply, please let me know your update on this when you have the time to check it out:)

Comment: It might take a few days as I am waiting for one collegue to come back from vacation.

Comment: So... I have by project build in Bamboo with an MSBuild task and have the tests run with NUnit, I'm getting the following in logs 11-Aug-2016 13:23:11 Tests run: 0, Errors: 0, Failures: 0, Inconclusive: 0, Time: 0.055277 seconds
11-Aug-2016 13:23:11   Not run: 0, Invalid: 0, Ignored: 0, Skipped: 0
11-Aug-2016 13:23:11

Comment: Can you please post what your NUnit runner task looks like ?

Comment: @MihaiAlex1986 I just edited my post and I confirm you that it is currently working in my setup.